# Why does my code start looping after I enter the income? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, if-statement, while-loop

When I enter the marital status, the code asks for income like it should, however when I enter the income, the code decides to loop and asks me the marital status again. Please help me!

````
while people < 1 or people > 20:##Setting up loop
    people = int(input('How many people would you like to process? '))##Reasking user if invalid number.
    
x = 0

while x < people:
    status = str(input('Are you married or single?'))##Input users marital status
    while status != 'single' and status != 'married':##Setting up loop
        status = str(input('Are you married or single?'))##Reasking if user is single or married   
    income = int(input('What is your income? '))

    if status == 'single' and income <= 50000:
        tax = income * .10
    elif status == 'single' and income > 50000 and income <= 100000:
        tax = 2500 + ((income-50000) * .12)
    elif status == 'single' and income > 100000:
        tax = 6000 + ((income-100000) * .15)
    elif status == 'married' and income <= 50000:
        tax = income * .05
    elif status == 'married' and income > 50000 and income <= 100000:
        tax = 2500 + ((income-50000) * .08)
    else:
        tax = 6000 + ((income-100000) * .10)


        print('Marital Status: ' + status)
        print('Income: $%.2f' %income)
        print('Tax: $%.2f' %tax)

        x = x + 1```
````

Comment: Because its in a `while` loop.

Comment: And `x` is still less than `people`

Comment: It skips the calculations and print part entirely and just asks what the marital status is again. Thats the main problem with this code and I don't know why it wont display the calculations

Comment: Are you sure `x = x + 1` is outside of every `if-else` statement? I can't see anyother problem with your code apart from the fact that the `else` block is eating up the code section that you are trying to be executed each time.

Comment: It should print the calculations before x = x +1 even becomes a factor, but it doesn't. It just asks the marital status after I input income

Comment: @CosmicSatum Code that you've pasted is poorly formatted. Please write with proper indentation. If you think it's already the same as your actual code, I suggest you to first move the last `prints and x=x+1` statement outside `else` body, but inside the outer-while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **last 3 print statements** and `x=x+1` are inside the else block.

You just need to **delete 1-tab space** before the **3 print statements** and the line where you increment `x`.

Here's the correct code:

```
while people < 1 or people > 20:##Setting up loop
    people = int(input('How many people would you like to process? '))##Reasking user if invalid number.
    
x = 0

while x < people:
    status = str(input('Are you married or single?'))##Input users marital status
    while status != 'single' and status != 'married':##Setting up loop
        status = str(input('Are you married or single?'))##Reasking if user is single or married   
    income = int(input('What is your income? '))

    if status == 'single' and income <= 50000:
        tax = income * .10
    elif status == 'single' and income > 50000 and income <= 100000:
        tax = 2500 + ((income-50000) * .12)
    elif status == 'single' and income > 100000:
        tax = 6000 + ((income-100000) * .15)
    elif status == 'married' and income <= 50000:
        tax = income * .05
    elif status == 'married' and income > 50000 and income <= 100000:
        tax = 2500 + ((income-50000) * .08)
    else:
        tax = 6000 + ((income-100000) * .10)


    print('Marital Status: ' + status)
    print('Income: $%.2f' %income)
    print('Tax: $%.2f' %tax)

    x = x + 1
```

This is a simple indentation error.

Comment: @CosmicSaturn if you find this code useful, please **mark it as useful** by clicking on the _up arrowhead_.